# How can I set up two, parallel buffers in emacs to edit Python files in one and execute in an IPython shell in the other?

Tags: emacs, elisp, ipython, advising-functions, defadvice

I'm trying to setup [`ipython.el`](http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/ipython.el) in emacs23.  I've successfully installed it (after putting `python-mode.el` in my `load-path` to supplant `python.el` which comes pre-installed with emacs).  And I can even get it to run via `M-x py-shell`, etc.

The interface seems to be pretty poorly setup, and I was wondering if I was doing it wrong, or if I need to customize it to make it work the way I'd like.

In short, the workflow I'd like to have:

- in one or more buffers, edit Python code
- When I hit `C-c C-c` in that buffer, either execute the Python code in that buffer in the open IPython shell buffer (if there is one) or open up another buffer to do that.

But what happens right now is:

- With the IPython shell in one buffer and the Python file in the other, if I hit `C-c C-c` in the Python file buffer, the file buffer switches to the IPython buffer (meaning I now have two, duplicated iPython buffers) and the file is executed.
- This is annoying.

I'm pretty new to elisp, but my understanding of [`defadvice`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) is that I could advise around `python-execute-buffer` to take note of the existing file buffer, run `python-execute-buffer`, and then switch back to the original file buffer as a workaround.

This seems pretty silly.  Any suggestions for better ways to accomplish this would be appreciated!

If it matters: I'm on OS X 10.6.8 with IPython 0.10.1 running Emacs 24.0.50.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not an emacs user, but I know of this, which may be useful: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/anything-ipython.el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that simply installing `python-mode.el` and `anything-ipython.el` and putting

```
(require 'python-mode)
(require 'ipython)
(require 'anything-ipython)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
                                (define-key py-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") 'anything-ipython-complete)))
(add-hook 'ipython-shell-hook #'(lambda ()
                                  (define-key py-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>")
                        'anything-ipython-complete)))
```

in my `.emacs` made everything work just how I wanted *if* `py-shell` is executed before `py-execute-buffer` (so that `C-c C-c`) executes the code in the shell instead of just opening up the `*Python Output*` buffer.